# Golang: Running something every few seconds with Ticker

Tags: go

I want to run something (update clients via websocket) every few seconds. I think I should use `time.Ticker`. But how do I get it to work? I have the below but its not working ...

```
func main() {
    hub = NewAppSocketHub()

    ticker := time.NewTicker(time.Second)
    go func() {
        for {
            log.Printf("In loop")
            select {
            case <-ticker.C:
                log.Printf("Broadcasting to %d clients", len(hub.Clients))
                hub.Broadcast <- UpdatePayload{
                    InstanceID: "Test",
                    Status:     "running",
                }
            }
        }
        log.Printf("Out of loop")
    }()

    r := chi.NewRouter()
    r.Use(render.SetContentType(render.ContentTypeJSON))
    r.Use(Cors)

    r.Post("/auth/login", Login)
    r.HandleFunc("/ws", WebSocketEcho)
    // ...

    http.ListenAndServe(":9000", r)
    log.Printf("Ended...")
}
```

I think you can ignore `NewAppSocketHub` and other app specific implementation. The problem I have currently is I get

```
2017/06/14 16:08:05 In loop
2017/06/14 16:08:06 Broadcasting to 0 clients
```

And it seem the loop breaks? Whats wrong?

Comment: What is the intention behind the `select`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that it's not known the implementation of `hub`, sending messages to the `hub.Broadcast` channel is blocking, therefore if nobody is consuming messages from it it will wait, preventing the loop to continue.

Comment: I didn't expect it but you are right. The `hub.Broadcast` is blocking because I did not run `Hub.run()` to drain items from the channel.